# Bone Parenting and Constraints

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I set up a spline IK for a tail rig and set up control points as well.
The only problem I have is that when I set the *Child_of* constraint to the control point in order to get a smooth flow, the control to the parent bone is lost.

Like when I attempt to move the rig fully, the bones will accelerate and go a lot further then they are supposed to go.

[image: Set Position]

[image: After just a bit of moving]

As it should be, all bones should stay in their original places when being moved with the main controller.

Comment: could you please share your file (armature only): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sure thing, apologies for the delay in response.
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6333" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6333/)